# Am I able to put uncooked chicken back in my fridge for a day?

Tags: food-safety, chicken, chicken-breast

I just took my chicken breast out of the packet and cut it up to make schnitzel then realised I had no oil. Is it safe to put it back in my fridge for a day?

Answer (score 2):

If it's within it's use by date and hasn't been out of the fridge for more than 2 hours since you bought it, then yes, it should be fine. Cover it well.